# add class to "li" with the href of a "a" inside

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an automatically generated table, so I can not put my hand in it. What I was wondering was, in one way or another, can I take the "href" of the element to and render it as if it were a class or id of "li" in order to be able to handle it with css?

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#section3"><span class="fp-sr-only">due</span><span></span></a><div class="fp-tooltip fp-right">due</div></li>
    <li><a href="#section4"><span class="fp-sr-only">due</span><span></span></a><div class="fp-tooltip fp-right">tre</div></li>
    <li><a href="#section5"><span class="fp-sr-only">quattro</span><span></span></a><div class="fp-tooltip fp-right">noBar</div></li>
</ul>
```

in short, the result should be

```
<ul>
    <li class="section3"><a href="#section3"><span class="fp-sr-only">due</span><span></span></a><div class="fp-tooltip fp-right">due</div></li>
    <li class="section4"><a href="#section4"><span class="fp-sr-only">due</span><span></span></a><div class="fp-tooltip fp-right">tre</div></li>
    <li class="section5"><a href="#section5"><span class="fp-sr-only">quattro</span><span></span></a><div class="fp-tooltip fp-right">noBar</div></li>
</ul>
```

I have not found much online. Do you know a method to do it? Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: It's not really clear what output you want to achieve. Could you please edit the question to show the HTML structure you want to create, and also the attempted jQuery code you wrote to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I take the "href" of the element to and render it as if it were a class or id of "li" in order to be able to handle it with css?

Yes you could do that using attribute selector and the jQuery `closest()` method like :

```js
$('a[href="#section4"]').closest('li').css('background-color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#section3">
      <span class="fp-sr-only">due</span>
      <span></span>
    </a>
    <div class="fp-tooltip fp-right">due</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#section4">
      <span class="fp-sr-only">due</span>
      <span></span>
    </a>
    <div class="fp-tooltip fp-right">tre</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#section5">
      <span class="fp-sr-only">quattro</span>
      <span></span>
    </a>
    <div class="fp-tooltip fp-right">noBar</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Maybe you solve my problem without complicating it as I did! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a CSS attribute selector like so:

```
[href="#section3"] {
    // css here
}
```

Alternatively, you could create ID's using jQuery from the href attribute:

```
const ID = $('li').attr('href');
$('li').attr('id', ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is a parent selector. Last I heard this is not possible. Once you select the `<a />` element, you can't traverse back up the DOM. 
Your options are:

- Apply css to the anchor elements
- Find a way to add classes to the list element through the backend
- Use js to dynamically add classes to the list element, as stated in a previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('ul li a').each(function(i)
    {
       var href = $(this).attr('href'); // This is your rel value
       var clsname = href.replace("#","");
       console.log("href",clsname);
       $(this).parent().attr("class",clsname);
    });
```

```html
<html class="has-navbar-fixed-top">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#section3"><span class="fp-sr-only">due</span><span></span></a><div class="fp-tooltip fp-right">due</div></li>
    <li><a href="#section4"><span class="fp-sr-only">due</span><span></span></a><div class="fp-tooltip fp-right">tre</div></li>
    <li><a href="#section5"><span class="fp-sr-only">quattro</span><span></span></a><div class="fp-tooltip fp-right">noBar</div></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```